# Laravel two references to same table

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-many

I have a transactions tables with sender_id and receiver_id columns which are both references of user.

now, I want to create a hasMany relationship for the user.
(all user's transaction, be it,received or sent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one relationship for all transactions:

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'sender_id')
        ->orWhere('transactions.receiver_id', $this->id);
}
```

But that's not a very elegant solution because it breaks eager loading.

The better solution is using two relationships and then merging them:

```
public function senderTransactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'sender_id');
}

public function receiverTransactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'receiver_id');
}

public function getTransactionsAttribute() {
    return $this->senderTransactions->merge($this->receiverTransactions);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$transactions = $user->transactions;
```

Comment: Tnx Jonas, didn't know there was a merge function

Comment: How would you call Sender Name, Receiver Name when you call senderTransactions

Answer (score 0):

Create sender and receiver hasMany relation on your User model and similar belongsTo in your transactions model

User.php

```
public function transactions(){
return $this->hasMany(Transactions::class);
}
```

Transactions

```
public function sender(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id');
}

public function receiver(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'receiver_id');
}
```

Comment: What I want is function transactions in the User model which returns collection of all transactions sent and/or received.

Comment: I have updated the code. Check if that works. You can pull all transactions (sent or received) via sender or receiver